# Why won't my Extjs checkbox send a true value for iOS on PhoneGap Build app?

Tags: javascript, extjs, phonegap-build

I have a `PhoneGap Build` app- cli-5.2.0. For this checkbox, the `neverExpire` is set and sent successfully in Android, but not for iOS. Why is this? I've included my js and `config.xml`. I've read about javascript's "truthiness" but am still not finding what's wrong. Can it be an iOS preference I don't have set?

```
this.neverExpire = new Ext.form.Checkbox ({
        label: 'Never Expires?',
        labelWidth: '80%',
        checked: false,
        listeners: {
            check: {
                scope: this,
                fn: function() {
                    this.expirationDate.hide();
                }
            },
            uncheck: {
                scope: this,
                fn: function() {
                    this.expirationDate.show();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    this.fields = new Ext.form.FieldSet ({
        style: { marginBottom: '.7em' },
        scope: this,
        autoHeight: true,
        items: [ 
            this.documentType,
            this.issuingCountry,
            this.issuingState,
            this.issuedDate,
            this.expirationDate,
            this.neverExpire
        ]
    });


<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="2.1.0" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="1.1.1" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="4.1.0" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="1.5.0" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="2.1.0" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="1.2.0" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="1.2.1" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="2.1.1" />


<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="orientation"      value="portrait" />
<preference name="target-device"    value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen"       value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="false" />
```

Comment: Where do you set the name of the field?

Comment: In a bean. Ext.regModel('DocumentBean', {
    fields: [ ...  {name: 'neverExpire', type: 'string'}, ...]

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are doing, because `Ext.regModel` is not part of the official documentation for ExtJS 6.0.1 or Sencha Touch 2.3.1. But if you set [`Ext.data.field.Field.name`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-modern/#!/api/Ext.data.field.Field-cfg-name) on your model, you are still lacking the [`Ext.field.Field.name`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-modern/#!/api/Ext.field.Field-cfg-name) on your form.

Comment: It's Ext 1.1.0. This is legacy code I inherited. Still learning how it works myself.